# GLSL and glVertexAttribPointer

Tags: opengl, glsl

Is it possible to know from inside a shader script if an attribute has been
enabled with `glVertexAttribPointer` and `glEnableVertexAttribArray`?

When I try to read the attribute without using the `glVertexAttribPointer` the program 
at least doesn't crash and the value seems to be 0.0. Is it valid to try to read
an attribute that isn't defined?

The problem I'm trying to solve is that I have two objects, one with attributes and one without and I would like to know if i can/should use the same shader program for both objects (assuming the value of the attributes is 0 for the object without them).

Answer (score 2):

> When I try to read the attribute without using the glVertexAttribPointer the program at least doesn't crash and the value seems to be 0.0. Is it valid to try to read an attribute that isn't defined?

For every attribute that has no vertex attribute array bound you're getting the value set using `glVertexAttrib` http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glVertexAttrib.xml which by default is all zeros.

If you have two different execution paths for attribute numbers, make this two separate shaders.